# Share user data between components in next 13

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt, nestjs

I have an nestjs backend that contain a login route, that route build an jwt and set an http only cookie with the jwt. On the next 13 frontend, the login is already done, i receive the cookie when the login was successful. The problem is: when the user is authenticated (cookie exists), I want to share his data across the application, like an welcome with his name, a profile page with his details/posts. How could I do that? I need too when the cookie expire or get deleted, this “state” need to be set to null/undefined.

I already read nextjs docs and got no solution.

Comment: On the Next.js server-side, for each page, if you detect your JWT cookie, perform a fetch to get the user; if successful pass it as props to your app, set the user in AuthContext so you can access to it deeply in any part of the application.

Comment: Based on what you telling to me, I think the next route handlers are the best option, like, catch the cookie, send him as bearer to a express-session to get users data. Correct?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data on each page by providing the cookie in the request to be validated in the backend.

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000', {
   credentials: "include",
}
```

Comment: So, I should verify the token, and if token exists send him as bearer maybe to a express-session?